# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, duplicates

I have a table called `tbl_jobs` that stores the meta data of some background jobs running in the application. The schema is like :

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_jobs` (
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_run_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `records_updated` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`,`last_run_on`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index2` (`type`,`last_run_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Whenever a job runs it makes an entry in the table with the `type` which is a unique identifier for different jobs, `run time` and the `records updated` in that run.

There are two different jobs that run at same time with types : `MAILER_UNLOCKED_REWARDS`
and `MAILER_ALMOST_UNLOCKED`.

When these jobs try to insert their entries with the same timestamp only one of them gets inserted and the other throws a **Duplicate Entry for key** error.

For instance the two jobs ran the following :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_jobs
            (type,
             last_run_on,
             records_updated)
VALUES     ('MAILER_ALMOST_UNLOCKED',
            '2012-08-22 19:10:00',
            'f8a35230fb214989ac75bf11c085aa28:b591426df4f340ecbce5a63c2a5a0174')
```

that ran successfully but when the second job ran the insert command

```
INSERT INTO tbl_jobs
            (type,
             last_run_on,
             records_updated)
VALUES     ('MAILER_UNLOCKED_REWARDS',
            '2012-08-22 19:10:00',
            '8a003e8934c07f040134c30959c40009:59bcc21b33a0466e8e5dc50443beb945')
```

It threw the error

```
Duplicate entry 'M-2012-08-22 19:10:00' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The primary key is combination of `type` and `last_run_on` columns.

If I delete the entry for the first job the insertion succeeds, i.e it is asking for `timestamp` alone to be unique.

However the conflict for the same `timestamp` occurs only between these two jobs.There are other jobs that get inserted for the same `timestamp`.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: can you show up the `show create table tbl_jobs`

Comment: Just a comment, I would recommend using a surrogate key. You may have more than one entry occurring each second.

Comment: Since a primary key is necessarily unique, you should remove the `UNIQUE KEY` line of your script.

Comment: Also, you may run into problems if you are defining your `type` column with `DEFAULT ''`. If you expect something in the column, you should not default it to empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the whole "type" field in your index? Or only the first character? Because the key MySQL is complaining about is

```
M-2012-08-22 19:10:00
```

instead of MAILER_...

Try running:

```
 SHOW INDEXES FROM tbl_jobs;
```

It should give something like:

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+    ----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tbl_jobs |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | type        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tbl_jobs |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | last_run_on | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

...

and I suspect it will show instead "1" in the Sub_part column of the PRIMARY index:

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+    ----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tbl_jobs |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | type        | A         |           0 |        1 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tbl_jobs |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | last_run_on | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

...

BTW, the primary key is always unique, so the second index `index2` you declare there is redundant.

Comment: I am using the whole type key. Cannot make out what M- is doing there.

Comment: @mickeymoon, the error reported for PRIMARY is inconsistent with the results. There's something wrong in the definition, I believe SHOW INDEXES will help (check the "sub_part" column).

Comment: @Iserni: As pointed out by you the `sub_part` is in fact **1** for the column `type`. but what implications does it have? and how to go about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing: you have to make sure you PRIMARY KEY was seted AUTO_INCREMENT.
The second thing: you just enable Auto increment by : 
    **ALTER TABLE [table name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1**
The third thing: when you execute the insert command you have to skip this key.

Comment: The primary key - in this case - is alphanumeric, so the `AUTO_INCREMENT` setting can't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error if I have a system shutdown or network problem. You really don't have a duplicate in your db. That is a MySQL db error. All you need to do is: if you do your insertion and it is not `true`, just alter one of the columns of your table you want to insert into either from `varchar` to `text` or `bigint` and then redo the insertion. That solves the problem.

```
If(!$insert)
{    
$alter=Mysql_query("alter table     

`table_name` change `table_name` 

`table_name` bigint(255) not null");    

If($alter){

//you then redo your insertion.     

} 


}
```